# Encryption with PHP and Decryption with Coldfusion

Tags: php, encryption, coldfusion

We are currently encrypting values from our website with PHP before writing them to a MySQL table.  We can successfully decrypt the values with PHP, however, we've developed a need to also be able to decrypt the data with Coldfusion.  Unfortunately we haven't been able to get that to work.  I'm looking for a solution that will do either of these two things:

1. Successfully uses our existing encryption code/data written in PHP and being able to decrypt it successfully with Coldfusion (preferred).
2. A modification to our existing encryption code written in PHP that can be successfully decrypted in Coldfusion.

Here is our current PHP encryption code:

```
private $cipher="AES-128-CBC";
  
                // Encrypt a value
  private function encrypt($value,$key){
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($this->cipher);
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
    $ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($value, $this->cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    $hmac = hash_hmac('sha512', $ciphertext_raw, $key, true);
    $encryptedValue = base64_encode( $iv.$hmac.$ciphertext_raw );
    return $encryptedValue;
  }
```

Here is our current PHP decryption code:

```
                // Decrypt a value
  public function decrypt($encryptedValue,$key){
    $val = base64_decode($encryptedValue);
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($this->cipher);
    $iv = substr($val, 0, $ivlen);
    $hmac = substr($val, $ivlen, $this->sha2len);
    $ciphertext_raw = substr($val, $ivlen+$this->sha2len);
    $decryptedValue = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext_raw, $this->cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    return $decryptedValue;
  }
```

I tried a decrypt test in Coldfusion with the following code:

```
<cfset TestString="ltlXr0hdv8kE9v+VVJ8GmLYVfgPSZPr9QCL89QoMupFJrXNdYmFi7sp0wbx8CbzJycmzblLDB/zF5pXrmRasMoW8PGV7tfjnEsxv8LUt7xj/56tAMHRJxIRk01TdpNvJ">
<cfset KeyString="7w!z%C&F)J@NcRfUjXn2r5u8x/A?D(G-KaPdSgVkYp3s6v9y$B&E)H@MbQeThWmZ">
<cfset NewString='#Decrypt(TestString, KeyString, "AES", "Base64")#'>
<cfoutput>#NewString#</cfoutput>
```

That fails, however, with the error:

> "Error","ajp-nio-8018-exec-7","09/25/20","11:26:48","","An error occurred while trying to encrypt or decrypt your input string: '' Can not decode string ""7w!z%C&F)J@NcRfUjXn2r5u8x/A?D(G-KaPdSgVkYp3s6v9y$B&E)H@MbQeThWmZ"".. The specific sequence of files included or processed is: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\scheduled\Decrypt_Test.cfm, line: 3 "

Note that the correct decrypted value is:  **Arlene**

Any ideas?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: What is the value you get for `openssl_cipher_iv_length("AES-128-CBC");`?

Comment: If you can give me a PHP snippet to determine that I have an environment where I can run it but honestly I don't know a whole lot of PHP code---I'm more of a Coldfusion guy.  The PHP routines were written by a former developer.

Comment: `<?php
echo(openssl_cipher_iv_length("AES-128-CBC"));
?>` may be try this?

Comment: Also, the value for `sha2len`.

Comment: Not a PHP dev, but I'm thinking that you're not CF decrypting the same value you're encrypting in PHP. Follow your PHP steps to see how you're decrypting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PHP code uses AES-128, i. e. a 16 bytes large key. But the applied key (`7w!z%C&F)J@NcRfUjXn2r5u8x/A?D(G-KaPdSgVkYp3s6v9y$B&E)H@MbQeThWmZ`) is much larger. PHP truncates too long keys according to the specified AES variant, i.e. for AES-128 only the first 16 bytes are considered, the rest is ignored. In the ColdFusion script the same 16 bytes key must be used.

In addition, in the PHP code IV, HMac and ciphertext are concatenated during encryption before the Base64 encoding and separated again during decryption after the Base64 decoding.
IV and ciphertext are required for decryption. The HMac is generally used for authentication, but this is not implemented here (to do so, the HMac would have to be determined for the received ciphertext and compared with the received HMac).
In the ColdFusion script no separation takes place, instead the concatenated data is decrypted directly, which fails. I.e. the missing separation must be implemented, then IV and ciphertext can be used for decryption.

The following ColdFusion script illustrates the logic which has to be implemented. The script can be executed [here](https://cffiddle.org/):

```
<!--- Hex encode encrypted data --->
<cfset EncryptedData=binaryDecode("ltlXr0hdv8kE9v+VVJ8GmLYVfgPSZPr9QCL89QoMupFJrXNdYmFi7sp0wbx8CbzJycmzblLDB/zF5pXrmRasMoW8PGV7tfjnEsxv8LUt7xj/56tAMHRJxIRk01TdpNvJ","base64")>
<cfset EncryptedDataHex=binaryEncode(EncryptedData,"hex")>

<!--- Separate IV (first 32 chars / 16 bytes), HMac(SHA512) (next 128 chars / 64 bytes), ciphertext --->
<cfset IVHex=Mid(EncryptedDataHex,1,32)>
<cfoutput>#IVHex#</cfoutput><br>
<cfset HMacHex=Mid(EncryptedDataHex,1+32,128)> <!--- Will not be used any further, see PHP code --->
<cfoutput>#HMacHex#</cfoutput><br>
<cfset CiphertextHex=Mid(EncryptedDataHex,1+32+128,len(EncryptedDataHex)-160)>
<cfoutput>#CiphertextHex#</cfoutput><br>

<!--- Truncate key to 16 bytes --->
<cfset Key=Mid("7w!z%C&F)J@NcRfUjXn2r5u8x/A?D(G-KaPdSgVkYp3s6v9y$B&E)H@MbQeThWmZ",1,16)>

<!--- Decrypt --->
<cfset KeyB64=toBase64(Key)>
<cfset IV=binaryDecode(IVHex,"hex")>
<cfset Plaintext=Decrypt(CiphertextHex,KeyB64,"AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding","hex",IV)>
<cfoutput>#Plaintext#</cfoutput>
```

With the output:

```
96D957AF485DBFC904F6FF95549F0698 
B6157E03D264FAFD4022FCF50A0CBA9149AD735D626162EECA74C1BC7C09BCC9C9C9B36E52C307FCC5E695EB9916AC3285BC3C657BB5F8E712CC6FF0B52DEF18 
FFE7AB40307449C48464D354DDA4DBC9 
Arlene
```

Comment: All I can say is a big THANK YOU.  This cryptography stuff honestly gives me a headache and I would never have figured that out but it works perfectly.  Now we can maintain the PHP encryption that we already have in place and still be able to work with the data on our side in Coldfusion.  I can't thank you enough!

Comment: @PaulB Don't feel bad. Encryption/Decryption is a topic that has likely contributed to the consumption of many gallons of good bourbon by developers. Especially those that work across multiple languages. It's both complex and simple. Complex in the inner functions of it, but simple in that you essentially have to duplicate the Encryption steps in reverse during Decryption. And know the details (like unspecified truncation) of each language used. Fortunately most languages follow a standard for their encryption schemes. AES in CF is AES in PHP, though the steps in the functions may differ.